# Detect if OpenGL ES 2.0 is available or not

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0

I'm creating an application for Android for API levels >= 7. One screen uses a `GLSurfaceView` with OpenGL ES 2.0 through the NDK. How can I detect if OpenGL 2.0 is available? I can't use `android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"` in my `AndroidManifest.xml` because I have to support all phones with API levels >= 7. If there is no support for 2.0, I will be showing a static screen.

I'm using similar code from the hello-gl2 sample app that comes with the NDK. In GL2JNIView, when it sets the OpenGL context, if it doesn't find an appropriate OpenGL config (in my case a config that requires OpenGL ES 2.0) it throws an `IllegalArgumentException("No configs match configSpec")` and the app crashes. I can't find a way to intercept that exception and do something else on that screen. Any ideas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's what I found in internets:

```
private boolean checkGL20Support( Context context )
{
    EGL10 egl = (EGL10) EGLContext.getEGL();       
    EGLDisplay display = egl.eglGetDisplay(EGL10.EGL_DEFAULT_DISPLAY);

    int[] version = new int[2];
    egl.eglInitialize(display, version);

    int EGL_OPENGL_ES2_BIT = 4;
    int[] configAttribs =
    {
        EGL10.EGL_RED_SIZE, 4,
        EGL10.EGL_GREEN_SIZE, 4,
        EGL10.EGL_BLUE_SIZE, 4,
        EGL10.EGL_RENDERABLE_TYPE, EGL_OPENGL_ES2_BIT,
        EGL10.EGL_NONE
    };

    EGLConfig[] configs = new EGLConfig[10];
    int[] num_config = new int[1];
    egl.eglChooseConfig(display, configAttribs, configs, 10, num_config);     
    egl.eglTerminate(display);
    return num_config[0] > 0;
}
```

Source: http://www.badlogicgames.com/wordpress/?p=343

Answer (score 7):

Maybe this can help

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

  // Check if the system supports OpenGL ES 2.0.
  final ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager)getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
  final ConfigurationInfo configurationInfo = activityManager.getDeviceConfigurationInfo();
  final boolean supportsEs2 = configurationInfo.reqGlEsVersion >= 0x20000;

  if (supportsEs2)
  {
    // Request an OpenGL ES 2.0 compatible context.

  }
  else
  {
    // This is where you could create an OpenGL ES 1.x compatible
    // renderer if you wanted to support both ES 1 and ES 2.

  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From the Android CTS's (Compatibility Test Suite) [OpenGlEsVersionTest.java](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/cts/+/master/tests/tests/graphics/src/android/opengl/cts/OpenGlEsVersionTest.java):

```
private static int getVersionFromPackageManager(Context context) {
    PackageManager packageManager = context.getPackageManager();
    FeatureInfo[] featureInfos = packageManager.getSystemAvailableFeatures();
    if (featureInfos != null && featureInfos.length > 0) {
        for (FeatureInfo featureInfo : featureInfos) {
            // Null feature name means this feature is the open gl es version feature.
            if (featureInfo.name == null) {
                if (featureInfo.reqGlEsVersion != FeatureInfo.GL_ES_VERSION_UNDEFINED) {
                    return getMajorVersion(featureInfo.reqGlEsVersion);
                } else {
                    return 1; // Lack of property means OpenGL ES version 1
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return 1;
}

/** @see FeatureInfo#getGlEsVersion() */
private static int getMajorVersion(int glEsVersion) {
    return ((glEsVersion & 0xffff0000) >> 16);
}
```

It actually provides a few other ways as well and the test verifies that they all return the same results.