# How to know what features are supported on a device?

Tags: android

I have read about how [filtering works on Google Play](http://developer.android.com/google/play/filters.html).

I also understand using `aapt` tool, we can [find out the features needed](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html#testing) from an apk.

But how do I know what features are supported on a particular device? I have a lenovo tablet which is incompatible with my app, but I could not figure out what feature is lacking on the device.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to write some code to validate your manifest restrictions.

For packages, like Maps:
[How can I learn whether a particular package exists on my Android device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6758841/how-to-know-perticular-package-application-exist-in-the-device)

For OpenGL:
[Detect if OpenGl ES 2.0 is available or not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6450709/detect-if-opengl-es-2-0-is-available-or-not)

If you've read the filting docs then you know that filtering is all handled in the manifest and explicit to what you filtered out.  This mean the short list of what this device doesn't support is something you've specified.  Post your list of restriction and people may be able to penpoint how to check a specific feature.

If you load the app on your tablet via ADB and it runs fine, I'd guess you have a restriction that you do not need.

Comment: I don't know of one, but that doesn't mean it doesn't exist.  It wouldn't be that hard to write.  Its just a matter of know all the things to test and reporting the findings.  You should post the restrictions from your manifest.  It may be something obvious.

Comment: I have solved the incompatibility issue. I know usually it can be solved by making `android.hardware.telephony` optional. However, as I copy and paste from the aapt output, I used the upper case `android.hardware.TELEPHONY`.. Therefore leading me to ask this question.

Comment: But I still think it will be helpful if someone knew of an app that can list the features supported easily.